# get user profile picture at registration

Tags: 7, users

I am using Drupal 7.

I follow [this](http://drupal.org/node/22271) link to enable profile picture of user.

Now i want to get profile picture from user at the time of registration.

How can i get this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a development version of the [Register with Picture](http://drupal.org/project/reg_with_pic) module.

Comment: Thanks but is there any way without external module?

Comment: This module doesn't have stable version for drupal 7.

Comment: Look at this new API function: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_account_form/7

Comment: You will only have to build your own module to house your custom code, if you want to do so looking at the module code will give you good insight on how to do so... However unless the module really doesnt work how you want it I cant see why you wouldnt use it.